# forall not completing for some domain sizes

Tags: chapel

I have the following code that is doing weird things with one of my student's modules:

```
forall i in cpus.domain {
    cpus[i] = new CPU(schedulerToCPUs, "" + i);
    begin {
        cpus[i].start();
    }
    writeln("launched CPU: ", i);
}
writeln("done launching CPUs!");
```

It is printinq out that it has launched all the CPUs, but it is not reaching the `writeln()` at the end.  This only happens when the size of `cpus.domain` is above 1.  (It seems to be okay when the number of CPUs is large, like 50.  I'm testing mostly on 3.)

The CPU class is my own design.  This is only happening for this one student's project.  I'm not sure what could be causing this problem.  I would really like some advice for where I can start looking.

Comment: Hi Kyle:  Is it possible to create a standalone version of this that didn't rely on the non-available-here CPU class?  Is the pattern that `cpus[i].start();` never returns?  (i.e., if I just create a version of this that puts those `begin` tasks into an infinite loop is that equivalent?

Comment: Style comment: `""+i` would probably be clearer written `i:string`

Comment: The more I stew on this one, the more baffled I am.  If all the writeln()s within the loop print out, all the forall loop's tasks should be complete, and the forall loop should definitely end (in which case the writeln() at the end should fire).  This makes me wonder if there's some sort of memory corruption in your student's program given that it's just one of them.  To test, you could set CHPL_MEM=cstdlib, CHPL_REGEXP=none and CHPL_TASKS=fifo, rebuild, and run with valgrind.

Comment: CPU.chpl is available on the project page: http://turing.plymouth.edu/~kgb1013/?course=4310&project=2  (alternatively, on the GitHub: https://github.com/paithan/OSChapelTests).  I can provide the back-up files used, but not on a public forum, as they're solutions to other projects.  The snippet in the Q is modified from testScheduler.chpl, also available on the course page and GitHub.

Comment: I tried running it after setting those variables, but without valgrind.  (It's not installed currently on our little chapel VM, apparently.)

Comment: Potentially important point: this is Chapel v1.16.

Comment: @Kyle - let us know if the suggestions from Brad helped here.

Comment: @bencray I'll be honest... I don't remember what was going on here or what worked to solve the problem.  I'll be paying attention again when this project launches for the students next month.